# How would I modify the drawing function to accommodate an extended array of shapes?

Tags: actionscript-3

I copied and pasted the source code into my code, then extended the tetrominoes array to include 5 more shapes. They are being drawn properly, but the DrawNext function is having issues accommodating them. What is the best way to code the function so it will use the extended array?

My code:

```
private function DrawNext():void {
    if (getChildByName("next")!=null) {
        removeChild(getChildByName("next"));
    }
    var next_t:Sprite=new Sprite();
    next_t.x=352;
    next_t.name="next";
    addChild(next_t);
    next_t.graphics.lineStyle(0,0xFFFFFF);
    //The problem is here! Everything in the Output windows points to either it or this method
    //i and j check to see if a piece in the grid is empty (0) or full (1).
    for (var i:int=0; i<tetrominoes[nextTetromino][0].length; i++) {
        for (var j:int=0; j<tetrominoes[nextTetromino][0][i].length; j++) {
                //When it encounters a 1, it draws a new sprite of a particular color
                //The color is determined by the piece that is being drawn.
            if (tetrominoes[nextTetromino][0][i][j]==1) {
                next_t.graphics.beginFill(colors[nextTetromino]);
                next_t.graphics.drawRect(tileSize*j,tileSize*i,tileSize,tileSize);
                next_t.graphics.endFill();
            }
        }
    }
}
private function BuildTetrominoes():void {
    // I
    tetrominoes[0]=[[[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0]]];
    colors[0]=0x00FFFF; //Cyan
    // T
    tetrominoes[1]=[[[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
         [[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
         [[0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
         [[0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]];
    colors[1]=0xAA00FF; //Purple
    // L
    tetrominoes[2]=[[[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
         [[1,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
         [[0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
         [[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]];
    colors[2]=0xFFA500; //Orange
    // J
    tetrominoes[3]=[[[1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
         [[0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
         [[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0]],
         [[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]];
    colors[3]=0x0000FF; //Blue
    // Z
    tetrominoes[4]=[[[0,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0]],
         [[0,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]];
    colors[4]=0xFF0000; //Red
    // S
    tetrominoes[5]=[[[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
         [[0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]];
    colors[5]=0x00FF00; //Green
    // O
    tetrominoes[6]=[[[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]];
    colors[6]=0xFFFF00; //Yellow
    //X
    tetrominoes[7] = [[[0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]];
    colors[7] = 0x00FF80;
    //U
    tetrominoes[8] = [[[1,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0]]];
    colors[8] = 0xFF007F;
    //V
    tetrominoes[9] = [[[1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0]]];
    colors[9] = 0xFF00FF;
    //Colon
    tetrominoes[10] = [[[1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
        [[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]];
    colors[10] = 0x0080FF;
    //Dot
    tetrominoes[11] = [[[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]];
    colors[11] = 0xFF4000;
}
```

The source code is nearly identical, except for shapes 7-11 in the BuildTetrominoes() function.

Comment: Please post PieceCanFit()

Comment: gbSprite is a movie clip. I'm too used to thinking of all my graphics as sprite sheets in XNA. :) I will add the PieceCanFit function ASAP. Would you like me to include the method in the original source code, as well?

Comment: If the error message says that exception is in the PieceCanFit function, then it is *exactly* there, not in a subsequently called function. Try to compile in the debug mode to see which line causes the exception. Ideally, use the debugger to see what's going wrong. Or post the code of the PieceCanFit function.

Comment: Done. I have marked the line at which the error is occuring.

Comment: According to the error message, you try to call a method or access a property on a variable that has *undefined* value. It is a special value and it usually indicates that no value has been assigned to an untyped variable. Another case when you get *undefined* is when you try to get a value from Object/Dictionary/XML object using non-existent key: var o:Object = {}; trace(o.someProp); // prints undefined

Comment: If row+i >= boardArray.length, then you'll get undefined. And thus you'll try to do undefined[col +j]. It will cause an exception.

Comment: This is the feature of Array class: if you try to access out-of-bounds element, you'll simply get undefined. Use Vector class to get explicit RangeError exceptions. Also Vertor is much better in terms of performance.

Comment: @sam.kozin Actually Vectors are slower except for when handling number types and strings.

Comment: Your gameBoard is 11x9 so the higher indices (The bounds) are 10 and 8 try if(col+j>=9) and if(row+i>=11)

Comment: @marty-wallace, I can't agree with you. I've written very simple performance test, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kozinsemen/4747047). Compile it with debug=false and run in the latest version of release player. You'll see that Vector is *at least* not slower than Array. On my machine/configuration (MacOS X 10.7.4, Intel i7, Chrome with PPAPI Flash Player 11.6.602.167) Vector is faster in all cases (numeric, string and object values), except creation (*not population*) test. My results: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OTaf5.png.